# Getting user input and check if it exists in txt file or not

Tags: python

I'm trying to prompt user input (product) and check if it exists in my txt file (line) or not. If YES, then go to my IF condition; if NO, then it should go to ELSE statement. But it is weird like everything output is opposite from my code.

This is the whole function for customers to purchasing. It get the groceries list from txt file and show to buyer to buy something.

```
def place_order():
try:
    fileHandler= open('groceries_list.txt','r')
    
except:
    print('File cannot be opened.')
    exit()
    
gro=fileHandler.readlines()

if len(gro) == 0:
    print("Sorry! There are no groceries in our store yet.")        
else:
    repeat = True

while repeat == True:
    try:
        fo= open('groceries_list.txt')
        fr= fo.readlines()
    except:
        print('File cannot be read.')
        
    order_list=[]
    total=0 
    view_gro()
    #################################################################
    product= input('Please enter groceries name you want to purchase: ').upper()

    for line in fr:
        line= line.rstrip()
        if product in line:
            print(line)
            line=line.split(",")
            print('The price for',product,'is RM',str(line[3]))
            line[3]= float(line[3])
            total=total+line[3]
            order_list.append(product)
            print('Product successful added to you shopping cart!')
            again= input('Do you need anything else? YES for continue or NO for quit.').upper()
            if again == 'YES':
                continue
            elif again == 'NO':
                print("Here's your shopping cart item")
                print(order_list)
                print('Total amount for your purchasing is RM',total)
                try:
                    while True: 
                        pay=int(input('You pay: RM '))
                        balance= total-pay
                        if balance == 0:
                            print('Pay successfully! Thanks for your purchasing')
                            fw= open('order_list_c.txt','w')
                            fw.write(str(order_list))
                            fw.write('\n')
                            fw.close()
                            repeat=False
                            break
                        else:
                            print('Pay unsuccessfully! Please try again.')
                            continue
                except ValueError:
                    print('Please enter numeric proper amount.')
                    continue
            else:
                print('Please enter YES or NO')
                print('==============================')
                continue
        else:
            print('Product not in list.')
            continue

fo.close()        
fileHandler.close()
```

This is the lists in my txt file:

```
    ['FOOD', 'vege', 2022, 40.0, 'fresh']
    ['CANDY', 'mentos', 2030, 10.0, 'sweet']
    ['BEVERAGES', 'sprite', 2025, 50.0, 'sweet']
    ['MEDICINE', 'PILLS', 2030, 300.0, 'allergy']
```

***Two situation from my code:***

1. When ask for user input (product): If I **ENTER NOTHING** it should go to ELSE and print('Product not in list') BUT it still go to IF condition and print(line) then comes out the first list until the last list in txt file if I continue enter nothing. And total up the sum of price of every lists even though i ask for NO CONTINUE. And write ['','','',''] into my new txt file since I have 4 lists in groceries lists.

This is output I get if I **ENTER NOTHING** in product input and enter NO to continue but it still keep going on the loop automatic until my lists finish:

```
    ['FOOD', 'vege', 2022, 40.0, 'fresh']
    ['CANDY', 'mentos', 2030, 10.0, 'sweet']
    ['BEVERAGES', 'sprite', 2025, 50.0, 'sweet']
    ['MEDICINE', 'PILLS', 2030, 300.0, 'allergy']
    Please enter groceries name you want to purchase: 
    ['FOOD', 'vege', 2022, 40.0, 'fresh']
    The price for  is RM  40.0
    Product successful added to you shopping cart!
    Do you need anything else? YES for continue or NO for quit.no
    Here's your shopping cart item
    ['']
    Total amount for your purchasing is RM 40.0
    You pay: RM 40
    Pay successfully! Thanks for your purchasing
    ['CANDY', 'mentos', 2030, 10.0, 'sweet']
    The price for  is RM  10.0
    Product successful added to you shopping cart!
    Do you need anything else? YES for continue or NO for quit.no
    Here's your shopping cart item
    ['', '']
    Total amount for your purchasing is RM 50.0
    You pay: RM 50
    Pay successfully! Thanks for your purchasing
    ['BEVERAGES', 'sprite', 2025, 50.0, 'sweet']
    The price for  is RM  50.0
    Product successful added to you shopping cart!
    Do you need anything else? YES for continue or NO for quit.no
    Here's your shopping cart item
    ['', '', '']
    Total amount for your purchasing is RM 100.0
    You pay: RM 100
    Pay successfully! Thanks for your purchasing
    ['MEDICINE', 'PILLS', 2030, 300.0, 'allergy']
    The price for  is RM  300.0
    Product successful added to you shopping cart!
    Do you need anything else? YES for continue or NO for quit.no
    Here's your shopping cart item
    ['', '', '', '']
    Total amount for your purchasing is RM 400.0
    You pay: RM 400
    Pay successfully! Thanks for your purchasing
```

2. Also when ask for user input (product): If I **ENTER PROPER ELEMENT IN LIST**, it comes out that list indeed but the ELSE statement ('Product not in list') also output together with the list that I input. Example: 4 lists in txt file. If i ask for the third list, it will output ('Product not in list') twice and my input list. Then, when I ask for YES, CONTINUE, it will loop from top and ask for user input again until I type NO CONTINUE, it ONLY OUTPUT THE LAST product that I input and WON'T total up the sum of price. And also ONLY write the last product from list that I input into the new text file.

This is output when I input **one of the element in list** but it work like this and wont total up the total price to me. ONLY write the last input into my new txt file even though I ask for CONTINUE.

```
    ['FOOD', 'vege', 2022, 40.0, 'fresh']
    ['CANDY', 'mentos', 2030, 10.0, 'sweet']
    ['BEVERAGES', 'sprite', 2025, 50.0, 'sweet']
    ['MEDICINE', 'PILLS', 2030, 300.0, 'allergy']
    Please enter groceries name you want to purchase: candy
    Product not in list.
    ['CANDY', 'mentos', 2030, 10.0, 'sweet']
    The price for CANDY is RM  10.0
    Product successful added to you shopping cart!
    Do you need anything else? YES for continue or NO for quit.yes
    Product not in list.
    Product not in list.
    ['FOOD', 'vege', 2022, 40.0, 'fresh']
    ['CANDY', 'mentos', 2030, 10.0, 'sweet']
    ['BEVERAGES', 'sprite', 2025, 50.0, 'sweet']
    ['MEDICINE', 'PILLS', 2030, 300.0, 'allergy']
    Please enter groceries name you want to purchase: pills
    Product not in list.
    Product not in list.
    Product not in list.
    ['MEDICINE', 'PILLS', 2030, 300.0, 'allergy']
    The price for PILLS is RM  300.0
    Product successful added to you shopping cart!
    Do you need anything else? YES for continue or NO for quit.no
    Here's your shopping cart item
    ['PILLS']
    Total amount for your purchasing is RM 300.0
    You pay: RM 300
    Pay successfully! Thanks for your purchasing
```

Comment: You should support your question with inputs and ouputs. It would make it simple to help you

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy... that's way to much code. Next time please try to reduce the text in your questions. Try to create a minimal reproducible example for the error you encounter.

I'm not sure wether I can  tell you all the things that go wrong here but here a few hints:

- If you enter nothing it should go to `else` but it doesn't: If you enter nothing the `product` will contain an empty string `""` which will be included in any string. Try this code:

```
product = ""
line = "'FOOD', 'vege', 2022, 40.0, 'fresh'"
print("{product in line=}")
```

- Only your last product is written into your file: You open your file with write (`w`) mode, therefore you clear the content in the file each time you open it. You need to open it in append (`a`) mode to not delete the content that's already in the file. See [Docs for open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).
- `continue` goes to the next iteration of the most inner loop. After your question `Do you need anything else?` you continue to the next iteration of the loop `for line in fr:` not to the next iteration of `while repeat:`.

Hope that helped... There are quite a few additional misunderstandings in the code (like the try-catch `Please enter numeric proper amount` should probably be inside the `while True:` loop) but these were probably the hardest to find errors.